# Get the count of entries from a json file

Tags: java, arrays, api, count, restful-url

I am trying to get json data from a fake api call and need to get the count of the items in it(so that in future I can call the actual restful service). I am not able to get the number of departments in the json. I am expecting the result as 4(int) here.

I am not able to get the string value(json) for the code below:

```
String json = client.target("file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/webapps/GetProducts.json").request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class);
```

Please find below the entire code:

```
String json = client.target("file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/webapps/GetProducts.json").request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class);

JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(json);

JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("locations");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

JSON Sample:

```
{
"Department":
[
    {"SectionId":"1","SectionName":"Childrens Wear"},
    {"SectionId":"2","SectionName":"Womens Wear"},
    {"SectionId":"3","SectionName":"F&A"},
    {"SectionId":"1","SectionName":"Mens Wear"}
]
}
```

I am new to java as well as api's.

Thanks,

Comment: `"locations"` vs. `"Department"`

Comment: Please address your actual problem in your question. Don't present one question and upon it being answered *then* ask your real question in the comments to that answer.

Comment: You can't get the string value because the path to your JSON has `%20`'s in places where spaces (`' '`) should be. `"file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/webapps/GetProducts.json"` should be `"file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/webapps/GetProducts.json"`

Answer (score 1):

You are either using incorrect key in code or you posted incorrect JSON example. You used `locations` as the key incode however there is no value against that key in sample JSON. You need to use `Department` as the key.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("Department");
```

Comment: Hi Harshil,That was my bad. Its actually "Department" in Code. Im not getting the output for the code: client.target("file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/webapps/GetProducts.json").request(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class);

Comment: Please update the question to include the corrections and the actual result you are getting.